# Search Banner Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, search

When searching on Windows 10, I have an annoying banner with text/logo (above the 'All Apps Document Web More' tabs).

Does anyone know how I can find how to edit/remove this?

EDIT:
This banner, in white. (I've scribbled out the logo/text for identifying reasons.)
Where do I find where this is stored so I can edit/remove it.

[image: Annoying Banner]

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Perform search and then go to `Search Settings` via the triple-dot menu.
2. Disable `Microsoft account` and `Work or School account` cloud searches

[image]